How I can recover extra word from myetherwallet?
I think I lost my extra word for my ethereum wallet mnemonics, how I can recover it? I have a clue for this word, must me simple and not big

Mnemonics are based on a word list defined by BIP39.
For English you can check the list of words defined in their repository https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt.

In MEW as addition to mnemonic you can add 1 extra word, like password which you can enter manually. I have mnemonics, need help with this extra word

The password is defined by you. It could be anything you wanted. There is no way to recover it if you do not have a backup.

Maybe there is some ways to brut password with some soft? I saw this for another passwords, I have also clue for my password it can be easier, if it can be
